Flutter Camera Macos package giving error after updating flutter SDK
Hello i updated my flutter and now when i tried to start my mac os app it gives this error and i dont know how to fix it. It starts after upgrading my flutter SDK. My macos version 13.1 and i dont want to update it to 14. Is there any way to fix this issue ?
Here is error message
/Users/burakerendemir/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_macos-0.0.8/macos/Classes/CameraMacosPlugin.swift:506:78: error: value of type 'AVCaptureConnection' has no member 'isVideoRotationAngleSupported'
                                    if #available(macOS 14.0, *), connection.isVideoRotationAngleSupported(self.orientation){
                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
** BUILD FAILED **

Here is my code
Future<String?> cameraFunc() async{
  List<CameraMacOSDevice> videoDevices = await CameraMacOS.instance.listDevices();
  for(var camera in videoDevices){
    if(camera.localizedName == "USB2.0 PC CAMERA"){
      deviceId=camera.deviceId;
    }
  }
  
  return deviceId;
  } 
RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: quarterTurns,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CameraMacOSView(
                      
                      deviceId: data,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      cameraMode: CameraMacOSMode.video,
                      onCameraInizialized: (CameraMacOSController controller) {
                         
                      },
                              ),
                  ),
                );

I updated package to the last version.But it still gives this error.
